# Request Validation using Observers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

With an observer, I add additional content to the model / database.
This works without problems!!

Now I would like to validate the incoming request, but unfortunately I do not know how to insert a validation or rules in the observer.

```
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'firstname' => 'numeric',
        'name1' => 'string',
        //'client_number' => 'required|string|unique:customers',
    ];

    /**
     * Listen to the updated event.
     *
     * @param Model $customer
     * @return void
     */
    public function saving(Model $customer)
    {    
        if (request('firstname'))
        {
            if (request('firstname') != null)
            {
                $customer->firstname = request('firstname');
            }
            else
            {
                $customer->firstname = NULL;
            }            
        }

        $customer->client_number = '123456789';
    }
}
```

Comment: You can validate request using `middleware`

Comment: and how could this look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you should avoid to use a Model Observer for request validation. There are other features that laravel provides for this, like the [Form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation).

On the other side, you can [manually create a validator](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) that runs inside your observer (or any other part of your code). Here an example that follows your question's code:

```php
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'firstname' => 'numeric',
        'name1' => 'string',
        //'client_number' => 'required|string|unique:customers',
    ];

    /**
     * Listen to the updated event.
     *
     * @param Model $customer
     * @return void
     */
    public function saving(Model $customer)
    {    
        $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), $this->rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // Fail logic
        } else {
            // Success logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't from an observer... that's why I wrote that is not a good practice to use the Observer for the validation....

Comment: OK, I understood that now!
But how should I proceed so that I can manipulate and validate a field in the Observer?

Comment: No, the best way is using the [form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: Is it possible to access an own form request from an observer?

Comment: @tognit no!!! The [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is used to track state changes on a model... What you're trying to do is using a fork to cut potatoes! It doesn't make sense! The validation logic must reside within a controller, a form request or a service, not on a Observer!

Comment: What do I want to achieve? I have a CoreModule and I would like to add additional fields via a CustomerModule (nWidart/laravel-modules).

That works with an Observer but unfortunately without validation.

Comment: How can you best manipulate a controller with a second controller or just add fields?

Comment: @tognit we're going out of topic... I've answered to your first question (and if the answer is correct please accept it) but If you have other doubts you shuld create a new one.